# R package: use a custom file/directories structure in pkg/R and pkg/src folders

Tags: r, package, directory

I'm writing a R package which begins to grow in size, and so would really appreciate to use a custom structure in folders pkg/R/ and (especially) in pkg/src/.

For example, let's say I have two families of algorithms of some type A, and some functions of type B, and a main entry point. Ideally R/ or src/ folders would be organized as follow:

- typeA/

  - algorithms1/

    - algo11.ext
    - ...
  - algorithms2/

    - algo21.ext
    - ...
- typeB/

  - function1.ext
  - ...
- main.ext

with "ext" in {R,cpp,c,f,...}, and potentially two files having the same name.

Is it possible ? If yes, how can I do that ?

Thanks in advance !

---

[2012-12-31] EDIT: an idea would be to write a few scripts - maybe inside another R package - to (un)flatten a structured package for tests or diffusion. But there is probably a better solution, so I will wait a bit.

Comment: You might ? be able to use a custom Makefile in `src/`.  Have you scoured the R extensions manual yet?  I think restructuring `R/` will be harder.

Comment: I tried to use a custom Makefile in src/, but although it ran well in command-line it failed when using R CMD INSTALL ("no rules to build target 'myfolder/myfile.c' needed for myfile.o"). I only found this paragraph about subdirectories organization http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories, and didn't see anything helpful inside. Nothing after googling a while either, so I tried here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the 'Writing R extensions' manual [indicates here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars), a Makevars file under pkg/src allows to have nested subfolders for C/C++/Fortran code. (See e.g. [RSiena](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSiena/index.html) package).

However, I didn't find anything concerning a custom structure in pkg/R. So I wrote a little package (usable, although needing improvements) which accomplish the following tasks:

- Load/Unload a package having (potentially) nested folders under pkg/R
- Launch R and/or C unit tests on it [basic framework, to be replaced (e.g. RUnit and check)]
- Export the package to be CRAN-compatible (flatten R code, generate Makevars file)

I will link it here if it reaches a publishable state. (For the moment I could send it by email).

Comment: Have you made progress with the package?

Answer (score 0):

The official package documentation https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html, section 1.1.5 contains this quote:

> The R and man subdirectories may contain OS-specific subdirectories named `unix` or `windows`.

I've tried creating a simple test package with subdirectories in R-3.5.1 and it did not work properly.

Nor `devtools::load_all()` nor `R CMD build` successfully exported code from subdirectories in R.